# Designing a helpdesk program

Tags: database, ms-access

I am trying to design a helpdesk program and this is my database design. Is it OK?

[image]

Also, I would like to have a net working time calculated for each ticket. Is it only possible with a query?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is Employees linked to both Ticket and TicketDetails? Can calculate the difference between start and end date/time in query or in textbox. If you are asking if can be done in table - not really because DateDiff function is not available to Calculated field type.

Comment: Is your help desk system all internal? i.e. Your company, your employees, your technicians? If so, I can envision a scenario where one of your technicians needs help desk support. In other words, employees and technicians are both 'contacts'. Not sure your formula for 'Net Work Time', but you could update that field when you enter the 'End Time'

Comment: Thanks guys.
As Gordon mentioned, a ticket is assigned to a specific employee, but multiple employees can work on it.
And yes, it is all internal but in this case the employees will only handle tickets and will never be considered customers

Comment: What are your natural keys and determinants?

Comment: Also check for improving the schema with groups, time zone, business hours. Is it based on 8/5 or 24/7 workflow, these need to be included in the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be clearer if you renamed the field TicketDetails.Assignee to .Worker. I'm thinking the ticket is assigned to one employee, but multiple employees might work on it.

Answer (score 0):

how to find Find employees who failed in aggregate (term1 + term2 + term3)

```
{
  "_id": 19,
  "name": "Levis",
  "results": [{
      "evaluation": "term1",
      "score": 44.51211101958831
    },
    {
      "evaluation": "term2",
      "score": 0.6578497966368002
    },
    {
      "evaluation": "term3",
      "score": 93.36341655949683
    }
  ]
}
```